# How to create client in MQTT with specific type of clientId?

Tags: react-native, authentication, mqtt, clientid

I am creating an application with MQTT implementation. For that, I have to login to the MQTT server with a specific clientId which includes a specific string in the initial part of the clientId. And with this clientId I'm not able to do login in MQTT server by code side.

But with MQTT-Explorer software I am able to login with the same credentials. If I change any word or later from clientId then I am able to do login by code side.

I have tried with various libraries but did not get success with any. What could be the reason behind it and how to fix the issue?

I am getting error as ahead.

```
mqtt.event.error connection failure Connection lost (32109) - java.io.EOFException
```

I have used "react-native-mqtt-new" library and my code for MQTT createClient and communication is as below

```
import MQTT from 'react-native-mqtt-new';

MQTT.createClient({
            uri: 'mqtt://mqtt.demo.io:1883', //for demo
            clientId: 'specific_string_randomnumber', //for demo
            user: 'xxxxx',
            pass: 'xxxx',
            tls: false
        }).then(function (client) {

            client.on('closed', function () {
                console.log('mqtt.event.closed');
            });

            client.on('error', function (msg) {
                console.log(client);
                console.log('mqtt.event.error', msg);
            });

            client.on('message', function (msg) {
                console.log('mqtt.event.message', msg);
            });

            client.on('connect', function () {
                console.log('connected');
                client.subscribe('test/#', 0);
                client.publish('test', "demo", 0, false);
            });

            client.connect();
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err, 'err');
        });
```

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67834711/edit) to show is the exact error you are getting.

Comment: updated the error.

Comment: What errors do you get client side?

Comment: Do you have access to the MQTT Broker error log? If so, what does it say when the login does not work?  There should be a log record of the failed login there too.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed. The reason for this issue is the library which I was using for my requirement. The requirement was to connect with the MQTT protocol 3.1.1 and with the "react-native-mqtt-new" library we are connecting to MQTT protocol 3.1.0 and that's why I was getting the error.

And for the solution, I have changed the library to "react-native-native-mqtt" and now it's working properly.